# Matrix multiplication kernel writen in OpenCL doesn't work when the matrix size becomes too big

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu

I wrote an OpenCL matrix multiplication kernel, which will do the multiplication of two square matrices.
The kernel code is

```
void kernel product(global const float* A, global const float* B, global float* C, int n){
  size_t kx=get_global_id(0);
  size_t ky=get_global_id(1);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     C[n*kx+ky]=C[n*kx+ky]+A[n*kx+i]*B[n*i+ky];
  } 
}
```

The host code that launches the kernel is

```
  // create buffer on the context
  int n=1000;
  cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(float)*(n*n));
  cl::Buffer buffer_B(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(float)*(n*n));
  cl::Buffer buffer_C(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float)*(n*n));

  float* A=new float[n*n];
  float* B=new float[n*n];
  float* C=new float[n*n];

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      A[n*i+j]=2.0;
      B[n*i+j]=2.0;
    }
  }

  //create the kernel, and set the buffer argument  
  cl::Kernel kernel(program,"product");
  kernel.setArg(0, buffer_A);
  kernel.setArg(1, buffer_B);
  kernel.setArg(2, buffer_C);
  kernel.setArg(3, n);

  //build the queue
  cl::Device device_use=all_devices[0];
  cl::CommandQueue queue(context,device_use);

  // queue manipulation: step 1: write the input buffer
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*(n*n), A);
  queue.finish();
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*(n*n), B);
  queue.finish(); 
  // queue manipulation: Step 2 run kernel
  queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(n,n), cl::NullRange);
  queue.finish();
```

Notice that A,B,C are square matrices with dimension n*n. I tried to run this kernel on  the Intel Iris graphics card on Macbook pro. It works well when n is small. However, when n is 2000 or larger, it will give the wrong result.  The maximum global work size is (512,512,512) for this gpu. So 2000*2000 certainly doesn't exceed the maximum. When I tried to run the kernel on cpu, I can always get the right result no matter how large n is. So the kernel should be right. Any ideas on what happened?

Comment: How big is your n, when the calculation yields the correct results?  What global and local working sizes do you have? The fact that it works on small matrices indicates that your kernel just does not work when more than one workg-group is working on the data (race conditions, work-group border violations, etc.). Also I'm unsure what strategy you use when processing the matrix. Could be your code (no offense) or me not being receptive and used to matrix processing kernels. Also your kernel is named simple_add, however that's not what it's actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, I just made some corrections to my question. The maximum global work size is obtained by making the call device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>(), which returns (512,512,512)@Park Young-Bae. I have corrected the kernel name to 'product'@Baiz. The kernel should be fine. I wrote the matrix in 1-d, which may be confusing. When I run it on CPU, it always gave the right result no matter how large n is. When I run it on GPU, it works fine when n=1000. But it doesn't work when n=2000.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your comment @ParkYoung-Bae. The kernel I launched is 2-d, which has the global size of 2000*2000. I think 2000*2000<512*512*512. So if I'm understanding it right, it doesn't exceed the max work size. As for the OpenCL implementation, I'm using the Apple implementation with C++ binding. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: you have a misconception regarding `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`. If it returns the maximum **local** work-size per dimension. So a local work-size of [512,2,1] is legal, as is [2,512,1]. However [1024,1,1] would be illegal as it violates the maximum size for the first dimension. **Important:** note that your local work-size is also limited in regard of the total number of work-items per workgroup. This limit should be queried with `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` and `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. It could be 512, in which case [512,2,1] would be illegal (512*2 > 512).

Comment: Host code posted! @ParkYoung-Bae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always experienced the same problems with the Intel integrated graphics on my own Macbook Pro, as do my colleagues. This could be due to the kernel execution taking too long and thus being killed by the driver in order to free up the GPU for other tasks (such as rendering to the display). Alternatively, it could just be a bug in Apple's OpenCL implementation (which has always been pretty flaky in our experience).

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. When the matrix size is too large, the operating system stops responding for several seconds, which agrees with what you said. Have you guys found a way to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: @and90 There's no nice solution to this, other than to split your kernel launches into multiple, smaller launches.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are several problems here. I'll try to address all of them (some might already be addressed in my comments).

OpenCL does not guarantee proper initialization of global memory. Some devices may initalize with zero, but some won't. However your code does rely on that because you're reading from global memory before a single value has been written to it: `C[n*kx+ky]=C[n*kx+ky]+A[n*kx+i]*B[n*i+ky];`. Additionally you're needlessly accessing global memory. You should not save the intermediate result in global memory, but rather in fast private memory (see improved kernel code which also handles the fact that C is not initialized).

You seem to be rather unclear about how OpenCL local and global work-sizes are handled, so I'll talk about this a bit.

Work-size limitations (your work-size must fulfuill all these requirements):

- `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` returns the maximum local work-size per dimension. So each dimension of your local work-size must be equal or smaller to the corresponding values. Example: `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` returns [512,512,512], so a local work-size of [512,2,1] is legal, as is [2,512,1]. However [1024,1,1] would be illegal as it violates the maximum size for the first dimension.
- `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` returns the number of maximum work-items per work-group your device supports, i.e. the maximum number of work-items within your local work-size. If `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` returns 1024, [512,2,1] is legal, as is [1024,1,1] but [1024,2,1] is illegal as 1024*2 > 1024.
- CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE returns the number of maximum work-items per work-group your device supports for this specific kernel. This usually is the same as CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, but it can be lower with kernels that use a lot of private and/or local memory.
- Your global work-size must be a multiple of your local work-size. This may seem a trivial thing if the size of your matrix is [2000,2000]. You choose your global to be the same size, OpenCL calculates the local work-size for you. I'll probably be [16,16] because those are the biggest divisors for 2000 and still yield a local work-size below 512. But consider this: your matrix is of size [905,905]. OpenCL will have to choose a local work-size of [1,1], which is the worst case ever in regard of performance (unless your device is smart enough to compensate for this bad working-size). 905 can't be evenly divided by any integer other than 1. Note that I could be wrong about this, but after reading a lot about OpenCL I suspect this is how it "has to" calculate the working-sizes. So, in order to get a high performance the work-groups generally should be no smaller than 64, but on modern devices 256 is a very good value. So you should calculate the global work-size from these values and adjust your kernel so it can handle more work-items than elements that need to be processed. Example: You want a work-group with size [16,16] = 256, but your matrix has 1000 rows and columns. Thus your global work-size should be [1024,1024] and your kernel should discard all work-items that are not needed. If you still want OpenCL to choose the local work-size, just change the global work-size to a multiple of 128 or 256 to avoid degenerate local work-group sizes.

Kernel code:

```
void kernel product(global const float* A, global const float* B, global float* C, int n)
{
    size_t kx=get_global_id(0);
    size_t ky=get_global_id(1);

    // Discard work-items that are not needed.
    if(kx >= n || ky >= n)
        return;

    float result = 0.f;

    int idxC = n*kx+ky;

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        int idxA = n*kx+i;
        int idxB = n*i+ky;

        result += A[idxA]*B[idxB];
    } 

    C[idxC] = result;
}
```

Kernel code end